# How to serve Senaite LIMS (Plone 4.3.19) with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Senaite is running on localhost:8080. Now, I would like to serve that to other people. I already have Nginx setup for https. With

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
```

I can access make the main page accessible, but the links generated by senaite all point to `localhost:8080` hard-coded in the generated html. Where can I change that so that my server address or relative links are shown?

Answer (score 0):

If Senaite runs under 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 and is configured to serve the lims under "senaite" the nginx configuration looks like this:

```
location / {   
    proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    rewrite                 ^(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/$scheme/$host/senaite/VirtualHostRoot/$1 break;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```